# How to add conditional case sensitive attribute in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, dynamic-attributes

I want to add 'tourAnchor' attribute dynamically, for which I am adding below line.

```
<div [attr.tourAnchor]=" feedbackIndex == 0 ? 'like' : null">
```

But, the attribute is being replaced to case insensitive and upon condition check, it is being converted as

```
<div touranchor="like">
```

Could you please help me to retain 'tourAnchor' to be camel case?

Comment: According to: https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#colspan
"Interpolation and property binding can set only properties, not attributes." 
So, it is not possible? I had to refactor the components a bit. Could be an useful feature.

Answer (score 0):

**Html** is not case sensitive and tags and attributes considered to be lowercase check [this](http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/html-tag-attributes.htm) ,
when I face this problem I use data attribute to save the key and another for the key

May be this will work for you

*template*

```
<p [attr.data-key]="'tourAnchor'" [attr.data-value]="'like'"  >
  tourAnchor - like
</p>

<p [attr.data-key]="'tourAnchor'" [attr.data-value]="'dislike'"  >
  tourAnchor - like
</p>
```

*style*

```
p[data-key="tourAnchor"][data-value="like"] {
  color:blue
}


p[data-key="tourAnchor"][data-value="dislike"] {
  color:red
}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-55098071)